# What to do with the code provided by facebook to generate Key Hash once it is copied in the main_Acitivity?

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

[At the bottom of this facebook developers troubleshooting link a code is provided.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/advanced)

What do I do with the code to get the key hash?

below is the code provided by Facebook

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         try {
             PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                               "com.facebook.samples.loginhowto", 
                                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
             for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                       MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                       md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                         Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                     }
               } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

              } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

              }
               ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the code to one of your activities and run the app. You will get the `HashKey` in Android Logcat.

You can copy the `HashKey` from Logcat and post in Facebook's Developer Console of the app.

Comment: @RutvijKarkhanis You are welcome !! As you are new user so I am telling you, if an answer solves your problem then you should accept it. To accept the answer just click on the green tick on left side of answer.

Comment: i'm not getting any hashkey, i did all that u said